# Spring Boot OAuth2 not redirecting to facebook

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm learning OAuth2 with spring boot. I've got a simple html file in my static folder,when I add `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` to maven dependency and request the html file from the browser spring boot redirects me to **http://localhost:8080/login** and shows a login form, But adding `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation to application class results in error **localhost redirected you too many times**
[image]
How to solve this issue?

When I try to use facebook for authorization by adding following **application.yml**

`security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 233668646673605
      clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
...`

Instead of redirecting me to **https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth** spring boot still redirects me to **http://localhost:8080/login** & shows **localhost redirected you too many times** error
What am I doing wrong? Why spring is not redirecting the request to **https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth**?

Comment: could you please post your security configuration code as well?

Comment: @SurajGautam I just added spring security to dependencies, didn't do anything else. I'm actually using code from https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate your own clientId and clientSecret from Facebook apps dashboard https://developers.facebook.com/apps , I don't think those two parameters are still valid.

Also, if you want a good tutorial for Facebook Oauth2 authentication I recommend you this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

Comment: Thanks, Generating own client Id and client Secret worked.